# Caching dynamically generated images on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, dynamic, heroku

For a list view of items, we have to dynamically generate (using RMagick/ImageMagick) icon images for every entry. This icon is then reused within the app. We thus want to omit generating it again, hence we should cache the image.

Ah right, our app runs on Heroku.

What is the best way to omit regenerating the icon? Some strategies come to mind:

- Caching with Memcache?
- Write file (and let Heroku/Varnish/Nginx) to the work?
- Use a gem like [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) to store to S3?

Answer (score 0):

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies

Best bet is probably memcache add on and to use fragment caching. Possibly  low level caching as another alternative.